# Form-builder with drag and drop functionality along with Custom fields(resource) to be created and can be reused

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, formbuilder

I need a form builder/editor where I can create my own fields using the basic controls(components) and configure them and then use them later. The form builder should have ability to handle the Layout ie. Header, footer and ability to handle the number of columns in a row while drag and drop.
I went through many links like:
http://selmanh.github.io/angularjs-form-builder/#/forms/create
https://github.com/MacKentoch/easyFormGenerator

the closest to my requirement are below two:

https://form.io/#/ 
 The form.io has the ability to create fields/resources that can be used later in form(like the way my requirement is). The greatest problem is that it is paid.
https://rawgit.com/MacKentoch/easyFormGenerator/v1.1.0/index_DragDropWay.html
 does not have the capability to create own fields and reuse them later. But has the attractive Layout handling.

The requirement is that it should be open source and is configurable

Answer (score 0):

Taake a look at http://bside.smaroofi.com. It has 12 grid colums system and json output so you can store it in database and resstore the form later. Also more than 20 control. You can create any kind forms you like.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am going through this seems like it is close to what I need but I have a quick question can I create custom reusable components too in this?

Comment: Yes, you can. it's very easy to add custom component.